# How to retrieve NServiceBus message headers in version 5?

Tags: nservicebus

I have the following line to obtain the message header within a IHandleMessages<> class

```
 IDictionary<string, string> headers = _bus.CurrentMessageContext.Headers;
```

I get the error message

> bus does not implement IManageMessageHeaders

I would have thought that this was configured as default. Does anyone know how to implement IManageMessageHeaders? Do I need to change how the endpoint is configured?

```
 public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint
{
    public void Customize(BusConfiguration configuration)
    {
        configuration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();
        ConfigureLog4Net();
    }

    private void ConfigureLog4Net()
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        var layout = new PatternLayout
        {
            ConversionPattern = "%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %m%n"
        };
        layout.ActivateOptions();
        var consoleAppender = new ColoredConsoleAppender
        {
            Threshold = Level.Debug,
            Layout = layout
        };
        consoleAppender.ActivateOptions();
        BasicConfigurator.Configure(consoleAppender);


        LogManager.Use<Log4NetFactory>();
    }
}
```

I'm using NServiceBus Host 6.0.0, NServiceBus 5.1.2.

Comment: Overall everything looks correct.  Are you running this in a unit test? If so, here is some info on that:  https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/2614

Comment: One more issue there https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/2683 but the actual code should work if the bus is not mocked.

Comment: My mistake, I made assumptions of how the nservicebus dependency injection work. IBus needs to be included in the constructor.